# Having "pop-overs" when clicking buttons - how do I position it with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want it to be positioned over content, so absolute positioning I assume is the way to go, so it won't push the other stuff away.

However, I want to make sure it's under the button that clicked it. If I use absolute position and set right to say 0 (the buttons are at the right side of the page, so I'm positioning the popover there) it works, but if I make the page wider or narrower it moves accordingly.

How do I make it stick to the area under the button but not push any content away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute position and z-index.

This center the `popup` in the window :

```
.popup {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; //half of the width
    top:50px;
    z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: I already know how to position it, it's just that when widening or narrowing the page it moves the pop over out of alignment.